# How to change the selected vertex bevel weight with python?

Tags: python, vertices, bevel

How do I change the *Bevel Weight* of the selected vertex using Python?
I need to find the selected vertex, maybe as a list?
and then change its bevel weight.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be in *Object Mode* to set the *Bevel Weight* via Python. In the following example I set all vertices of my *Default Cube* or `bpy.context.object` to have `bevel_weight = 0.77` and then override the vertex at index 0 to have a `bevel_weight = 0.44`.

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

obj = bpy.context.object
vertices = obj.data.vertices

# change bevel weight for every vertex
for v in vertices:
    v.bevel_weight = 0.77

# change bevel weight for selected vertex
selected_verts = [v for v in vertices if v.select]
for v in selected_verts:
    v.bevel_weight = 0.55

vertices[0].bevel_weight = 0.44 # change bevel weight for vertex at index 0
```

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I needed.

Comment: you're welcome!